# Leaflet: Snap to grid

Tags: leaflet, snapping

I am trying to make leaflet markers snap to a grid (e.g. 10px) when dragging.
The only method I can think of so far is to re-implement `L.Draggable` so that the `offset` calculated in `_onMove` is rounded to the nearest multiple of the grid size.

Is this the best way to do this? (Will it even work to override it then re-assign it to `L.Draggable`?)

I have seen plenty of questions about snapping features to another feature, which is relatively easy since you can just listen to `dragend` and do the snap at the end of the move. In this case I need to snap each 'drag'..

Comment: Try this leaflet plugin [Leaflet.Snap](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Snap). Easy to install and implement

Comment: Nope, this will snap to other features. As noted in the question; there is plenty of info about this. I want to snap to a 'grid' (I.e every movement of a marker or feature is forced to land on a grid point, meaning you cant move a feature by less than 5 pixels or whatever the grid size is)